# How can you use python to append lower-level ASCII characters to a (notepad) document?

Tags: python, null, byte

I need to reach a specific byte count and want to fill the rest of document with null bytes such as lower-level ascii characters. I've heard there's a way using python but I'm unsure how to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chr()` for this, for example:

```
t = "BLA"
t += chr(33)
print(t)
```

will print `BLA!`. 33 is the decimal value for "!". Use any other value you like, loop over your string and write it to a new file (use `open`, `read`, and `write`, of course to accomplish this on a file base).

Edit: Use

```
file_ptr = open("filename.txt", "r")
t = file_ptr.read()
```

for example to grab your file's contents.

Comment: file_ptr = open("test.txt", "r"), file_ptr.write(chr(1)) This gives an "unsupported operation" error. Where am I going wrong here. I'm trying to write the low level ascii character to the text file

Comment: You MUST write to the content behind the file_pointer. To get the content, you have to read it. store the result into another variable. Merge my initial answer and the edit. Edit before the initial answer:

```
file_ptr = open("filename.txt", "r")
t = file_ptr.read()
t += chr(33)
print(t)
```

The rest (how to write the modified value behind `t` to some file) is your exercise.